# How to index a jsonb array field to perform range query on each record in the array in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table `reports` with a `jsonb` field `items`. For each item in the report, it contains a field called `score` (other fields are unrelated to this question).

```
reports
id, items
1, [{"score": 1.0}, {"score": 2.0}]
2, [{"score": 3.0}, {"score": 9.0}]
```

Is it possible to add index so that it's fast for the query "give me all the reports with at least one item.score > 5"?:

```
SELECT id FROM reports where items @? '$[*] ? (@.score > 5.0)'; 
// will return id = 2
```

I have tried gin index on `items` but it only works for exact matches such as `@.score == 5.0`

Comment: Why not just use a properly normalized data model. Then indexing and efficient queries become quite easy.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @a_horse_with_no_name , just want to know if it's possible in postgres jsonb

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html
GIN INDEX cannot index-only-scan.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING

> The default GIN operator class for jsonb supports queries with the
> key-exists operators ?, ?| and ?&, the containment operator @>, and
> the jsonpath match operators @? and @@.

So **@?** is supported.
[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a371924dbd384a2e4a8f0adbf3a9308b)

```
CREATE INDEX jidx ON test1 USING gin (data jsonb_path_ops);

SET enable_seqscan = OFF;

EXPLAIN (
    COSTS OFF
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    test1
WHERE
    data @ ? '$[*] ? (@.score > 5.0)';
```

Further tutorial: https://pganalyze.com/blog/gin-index

Comment: But this only uses the index to rule out rows which don't have a score field.  If every row has one, this will be slower than the seq scan plan.

Comment: @jjanes thanks for pointed out. I haven't thought about it....

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function which returns the max score, then index that function and rewrite the query to use it.

```
create function max_score(jsonb) returns float language sql as $$ 
  select max((value->'score')::float) from jsonb_array_elements($1); 
$$ immutable;

create index on reports (max_score(items));

SELECT id FROM reports where max_score(items) > 5;
```

Obviously the max score being >5 is identical to at least one score being >5.  This type of reduction won't be possible in all cases, so you should still consider a better data model.